# CCActionSequence for two different objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sequence, ccaction

I want to move two different objects, pane1 and pane2, simultaneously using CCActionMoveTo, and I want to call a function once these two objects finish moving.

```
CCActionMoveTo * actionMove1 =  [CCActionEaseOut actionWithAction:
                               [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:.4
                                               position:ccp(pane1.position.x - 150, 0)]
                                               rate: 1.5];


CCActionMoveTo * actionMove2 =  [CCActionEaseOut actionWithAction:
                                [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:.4
                                                          position:ccp(pane2.position.x - 150, 0)]
                                                            rate: 1.5];

[pane1 runAction: actionMove1];
[pane2 runAction: actionMove2];
[self generateTerrain];
```

How do I call these two actionMoves at the same time and wait until both are done to call generateTerrain?

Comment: see my full answer to your other question ... group pane1 and pane2 in a combinedPane node, and run the action on combinedPane.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by just making a timer that calls generate terrain after .4 seconds like this

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.4 target: self
                               selector: @selector(generateTerrain:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
```

As for executing the animations simultaneously, the code you have should run them at the same time as they are on different nodes

Hope that helps!

Comment: Suppose I don't want to call a specific function. Is there any way to wait .4 seconds before moving forward in the code?

For example, instead of calling generateTerrain, after 0.4 seconds it would just jump to a goto statement

Comment: cocos2d has api for this, dont mix NSTimer with cocos2d ... you may not like the result.  use [self scheduleOnce:delay:] or [self scheduleBlock:delay];

Comment: There you have it, the block with delay should solve the issue. you cant just fully pause a certain flow of your code because certain processes need to run for your app to live. If you have stuff that you want to wait, temporarily disable it or move it into the block after delay